# RSpec View Tests and content_for :title

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I'm trying to test the **title** tag of my `application/layout.html.erb`:

```
<title><%= content_for?(:title) ? yield(:title) : "Foo Bar" %></title>
```

But I find no way to set the **title** variable:

```
it "should show a title" do
  # NameError: `title' is not allowed as an instance variable name
  #view.instance_variable_set(:title, 'Test Title')

  # Deprecation error
  # view.stub(:title) { 'Test Title' }

  # Fail:
  # allow(view).to receive(:title) { 'Test Title' }
  # view.content_for(:title) { 'Test Title' }
  # assign(:title, 'Test Title')
  # helper.stub(:content_for).with(:title).and_return('Test Title')

  render

  expect(rendered).to have_title('Test Title')
end
```

I'm using Rails 4.1.4, rspec-rails 3.0.2, Capybara 2.4.1. Any suggestions?

Comment: Is this in a spec for your action's view or the layout? View specs don't render their layouts. If this is *already* in a spec for your layout `view.content_for(:title) { 'Test title' }`, should be all you need...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
 view.instance_variable_get("@view_flow").set(:title,"Test Title")
 render
 expect(rendered).to have_title('Test Title')
```

Answer (score 6):

In case you need to test the result of a `content_for` block, you can access it with

```
view.content_for(:title)
```

Not strictly related to the question but useful for similar cases if you end up here googling for this.

Comment: It worked for me to test as: `expect(view.content_for(:subnavigation)).to have_content("Change Region")`

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone needs to do this with Minitest:

```
def setup
  @view_flow = ActionView::OutputFlow.new
end

test 'when page_title is set' do
  @view_flow.set(:page_title, "Hello") 
  expected_html = '<title>Hello | My Amazing Website</title>'
  assert_equal expected_html, title
end
```